# For article in biblatex-chicago which field for the editor of the journal?

Tags: biblatex

I am getting the impression that biblatex-chicago places the editor of a journal in the wrong position, or am I getting something wrong? Shouldn't the editor be printed after the title of the journal?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@article {myarticle,
author = {me},
year = {2015},
title = {my article's title},
pages = {30--60},
journaltitle = {The Journal Title},
volume = {1},
editor = {Mr. Editor},
location = {somewhere},
}



\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I'd say no: look at §.14.187 (16th ed): "extra" information goes before the `journaltitle` field.  Furthermore: consider this useful point of advice from the `biblatex-chicago` manual (§.4.5.2): "One useful rule, when you are having difficulty creating a .bib entry, is to ask yourself whether all the information you are providing is strictly necessary. The Chicago specification is a very full one, but the Manual is actually, in many circumstances, fairly relaxed about how much of the data from a work’s title page you need to fit into a reference."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I was wrongly informed about the concerned entry being a an article published in a journal. The presence of an `editor` (and `location`) should have alerted me earlier that I'm actually dealing with a contribution to an edited volume, so that `@incollection` is the correct entry type. Not so much a technical problem than one of careful reflection of the data one is dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

No way.

Thou never shalst mention the editor of a journal (and if, don't use `biblatex-chicago`. Use `\usepackage[style=authoryear`(or something else, but *not*`style=chicago`)`]{biblatex}`.).

There is actually a field `editor` in `@ARTICLE`-entries, which is used only for special issues, where there is an `issuetitle`. `biblatex-chicago` thinks, he/she is the editor of your article, in case you are stabbed. (The same holds, btw, for editors of book-series, which are never quoted.).

*If* you actually want to, you can either have to look for an appropriate bibliography style or experiment with

```
@article{myarticle,
entrysubtype = {magazine}, %!!!
author = {Me},
year = {2015},
title = {my article's title},
pages = {30--60},
journaltitle = {The Journal Title},
number = 1,
volume = 3,
usera = {\partedit{Mr. Editor}}
}
```

Note: In this case, `volume` no longer works, so you have to format `number` that it looks like `volume+number`.

So, try `\usepackage{biblatex}` and use any of the `.bbx`-styles apart from `chicago.bbx` and friends and relatives.

Comment: 'Thou shalt not...' perhaps? If you must.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question.  The question is whether `biblatex-chicago` puts the editor information in the wrong place, not whether it is a good idea to do it. Regarding placement, it is clear that it is the "right" place; and regarding whether to do it, we can't answer in the context of the "author-date" Chicago style since we don't set the rules (I assume this is true for you also). In general, I agree that an editor should probably only be mentioned in "special issues" and so on, but it is hard to make a *rule* for *all other cases*.

Comment: It is rather an ontological question: In the `biblatex-chicago`-world there are simply no editors of journals (there aren't publishers either, though in some people's world there are), which accordingly can't be put in any place, neither right nor wrong, only editors of single articles. These are put in the right place, the others don't exist. Journal editors can only be faked (making the journal a magazine). So you have to enter a new world.